# How to limit bandwidth after a threshold is reached [Mikrotik]?

Tags: networking, home-networking, bandwidth, rules, mikrotik-routeros

My router is [Mikrotik RB951G-2HnD](http://routerboard.com/RB951G-2HnD) and I would like it to limit the connection speed to a particular website once some amount of traffic between the user and the website has passed. The website ip range is known, the user is set up by `dhcp`.

1. There is a `connection-bytes` switch for `/ip firewall mangle` rules. I could start marking packets or send users to an `address-list` based on that switch. However, I can't single out the user in this case. Every user connected to the website will contribute to reaching the threshold and then everyone will get a speed limit.
2. It looks like the [User Manager](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/User_Manager) package might be what I am looking for but it's not preinstalled on the router and I would like to avoid installing extra stuff if at all possible.
3. And there is RADIUS which, judging by wikipedia, is pretty hard to understand let alone install. Looks like an overkill.

Is there a *simple* way to limit the speed of a particular user-to-website connection after a certain threshold has been reached? Am I missing something *builtin*?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Simple Queue in the Queues section. Just set the website IP address as the Dst : and go to the Advanced tab to manage the threshold you want (Limit at).